# iOS customize scrollbar in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, scrollbar, customization

In iPhone I am going to customize the scrollbar of UITableView with images.
But I didn't find correct method.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you are asking not clear add more details to your question..

Answer (score 1):

firstly you have to uncheck showVerticalIndicatir and showHorizontallIndicatir in the Interface Builder.

then in the ViewDidLoad methode add :

```
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scrollViewBarImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    UIImage *imgBar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scroller.png"];
    [self.scrollViewBarImgView setImage:imgBar];
    CGRect frame = scrollViewBarImgView.frame;
    frame.size.width = 8;
    frame.size.height = 60;
    frame.origin.x = 312;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [self.scrollViewBarImgView setFrame:frame];

[self.tableView addSubview:scrollViewBarImgView];
```

then in the - (void)scrollViewDidScroll methode :

```
CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
CGRect frame = self.scrollViewBarImgView.frame
float fact = (cellHeight*numberOfRow+ indicatorBarHeight) / tableViewHeight;
frame.origin.y = offset.y + (offset.y/fact);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
[self.scrollViewBarImgView setFrame:frame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I've used this solution with some modifications. For example, the animation section isn't necessary; in fact, it creates some lags in the scrolling. 
Thanks @SOUA Hamza.